How to automatically reconnect WebSocket in Flutter app for real-time chat?
I'm developing a Flutter chat application using WebSocket for real-time communication. The WebSocket connection sometimes disconnects unexpectedly, and I'm looking for a way to automatically reconnect when this happens.
I've tried implementing a reconnect mechanism using a Timer to periodically check the connection status and reconnect if disconnected. However, this approach feels inefficient and may not be the best practice.
Is there a more efficient and reliable method to automatically reconnect a WebSocket in Flutter when it disconnects? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
Future<void> _connect() async {
print("connection function");
try {
  print('try start');
  _socket = await ws.WebSocket(
      Uri.parse('$webSocketUrl?userID=${Common.user?.user.id}'));
} catch (e) {
  print('error on connecting $e');
}

_socket.messages.listen((data) async {
  if (data.toString().contains('No receiver user found')) {
    print(data);
    data.toString().printInfo();
    return;
  }
  if (data != "success") {
    Message message = Message.fromJson(jsonDecode(data));
    if (message.remoteId == user.id) {
      _addRecentChatUser(message.author.id);
    }
    if (message.status != Status.delivered) {
      message = await getMessageData(message, Status.delivered, "receive");
      print("message status here ${message.status}");
      print("message here before: ${message.toJson()}");
      if (message.type != MessageType.text) playSound();

      receivedMessage.value = message;
      await incomingOutgoingMessages.singleMessage(
          receivedMessage.value, "receive");
      message = message.copyWith(
          author: User(id: message.remoteId.toString()),
          remoteId: message.author.id.toString());
      _socket.send(jsonEncode(message));
      Get.find<HomeController>().getSortChatUser();
    } else
    if (message.status == Status.delivered) {
      message = receivedMsg.value.copyWith(
          author: User(id: Common.user!.user.id!),
          remoteId: message.author.id,
          status: Status.seen);

      ChatModel chatModel = ChatModel();
      chatModel.message = jsonEncode(message);
      try {
        await SQLiteDbProvider.db
            .updateLastInsertedRecord(chatModel.toJson(), dummyChatTable);
        await SQLiteDbProvider.db
            .deleteRowFromTable(chatModel.id!, pendingSendMessagesTable);

        await SQLiteDbProvider.db
            .updateColumn(chatUsersTable, 'lastMessageTime',
            '${message.createdAt}', '${message.remoteId}')
            .then((value) => Get.find<HomeController>().getSortChatUser());
      } catch (e) {
        print('error on connecting $e');
      }
      sendMessage.value = message;
      Get.find<HomeController>().getSortChatUser();
    }
  }}, onDone: () {
    "connection done".printError();
  }, 
    onError: (value) {
    "error in connection $value".printError();
  }

  );
}

}
